# Why I can't submit my form to Database when I pass `LoginRequiredMixin` to my `view` in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm new to `Django` and I'm trying to make a very simple app for my coworkers to submit their tasks on a client and how long took them to fulfill their task.

I can submit to my model through the admin page fine but I can't submit it as a form through the HTML page.

I'm using `django-autocomplete-light` which is working fine as well.

```py
# This is my forms.py file
class PushTask(ModelForm):
    name = CharField()
    class Meta(object):
        """docstring for Meta."""
        model = ClientModel
        fields = ['name', 'reason', 'time_spent']
        widgets = {
            'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='name-autocomplete'),
        }
```

```py
# This is a part of my models.py file
class ClientModel(models.Model):
    Aa = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Clientele, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_spent = models.TimeField(default=None)
    dec_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    reason = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name
```

```py
# ths is my views.py which I believe is causing the issue

class RecordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'manage_records.html'

    def get(self, request):
        print('I got the form ')
        formset = PushTask()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request):
        print('I posted ')
        formset = PushTask(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
                ClientModel(name=name, reason=reason, time_spent=time_spent, 
                            dec_name=request.user)
                formset.save()
                formset = PushTask()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('manage_records.html')
        args = {'formset': formset}
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'formset': formset})
```

```html
<!-- this is my html form -->
<form method="POST" id="former">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.as_table }}
</form>
```

The desired outcome is when the user submits the form, to save everything to my database and clean the form for the user to reuse it.

Comment: Please can you describe the issue and the error you are facing exactly ?

Comment: @PRMoureu As I said to my title, the form won't submit after I changed `RecordView(TemplateView)` to `RecordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `views.py` as I suspected. I believe this piece of code
`return render(request, self.template_name, {'formset': formset})`
run before the form got the chance to check for validation.

The correct code:

```py
# views.py
class RecordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'manage_records.html'
    username = ''
    def get(self, request):
        print('I got the form ')
        form = PushTask()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


    def post(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print('prepost')
            form = PushTask(request.POST)
            print('I\'m in post function')
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                # profile.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
                profile.dec_name = request.user
                profile.save()
                return redirect('recorder')
            print('Prob Not')
            args = {'form': form}

            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

I would gladly accept any other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You construct a `ClientModel` with:

```
ClientModel(name=name, reason=reason, time_spent=time_spent, 
            dec_name=request.user)
```

But that does not make any sense, since your `ModelForm` is supposed to do that, and becuase `reason`, `time_spent`, etc. are all not defined.

You furthermore seem to redirect to a template name, not the name of a view (or the path of a view).

The above looks a lot like a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), therefore I strongly advice to use such view, and alter behavior you want to change:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class RecordView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'manage_records.html'
    form_class = PushTask
    success_url = reverse_lazy('some-view-name')
```

Here the form will have as name `form` in your template, not `formset`, but your form is *not* a [*formset* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) in the first place anyway.

> **Note**: usually forms in django have a `Form` suffix, to avoid confusion with models. You thus might want to use `PushTaskForm` over <s>`PushTask`</s>.

Comment: I used `formset` indeed because I was lazy to change the previous setup the same goes for the `return HttpResponseRedirect('manage_records.html')`. I changed the names , I tried your solution but sadly it didn't work.  I debugged the code it doesn't even run ` def post(self, request):` .

Comment: @Magotte: did you define a `<input type="submit">` button?

Comment: I'm using a js script
```javascript
function checkSubmit(e) {
   if(e && e.keyCode == 13) {
      document.forms[1].submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Magotte: It might be better to first check if it works without this JavaScript, since then it is clear where the error occurs.

Comment: Still nothing... I believe the functions `post` and `get` are causing the problem.

Comment: @Magotte: hold on, in the `CreateView` you should *not* define `get` and `post` methods in the first place (at least not for something simple as this).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort I'll try to focus on `CreateView`.

Comment: @Magotte: since your `name` field is a `ForeignKey` to `Clientele`, you can not just use a `CharField`. You either use a `ModelChoiceField`, or you should change your `ForeignKey` to a `CharField`.

Comment: Yes but then I will lose the `autocomplete`. I want the user to write into an input field instead of using a dropdown menu.

Comment: @Magotte: not at all. You realize there is a difference between a form field, and a widget.

Comment: I solved the problem I will post the solution soon. Yeah, I can tell the difference, yet the form renders as a `<select>` in my `html` page. I want to render as an `<input>` tag.